# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor, but class was expected

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am struggling with this error , when i am publishing my JSP application in Tomcat7.0 i am getting this error

`javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor, but class was expected`

I don't know the exact reason for this error.

Comment: Reason here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IncompatibleClassChangeError.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IncompatibleClassChangeError is usually caused by compiling against one version of a library and executing against a different version.

I would ensure that the version of JDK used for Tomcat7 is the same version as compiled `org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor`